# Find rank of a player based on 2 fields in a collection in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have more than 100,000 documents in a collection and I want to get rank of player based on his `totalCoins` field first and in case 2 players have same coins, then based on their `level`.

Below is Player collection example:

```
const players = [
{
   _id: 1,
   name: "abc",
   totalCoins: 100,
   level: 1
},
{
   _id: 2,
   name: "bcd",
   totalCoins: 200,
   level: 2
},
{
   _id: 3,
   name: "cde",
   totalCoins: 300,
   level: 3
},
{
   _id: 4,
   name: "def",
   totalCoins: 100,
   level: 4
},
{
   _id: 5,
   name: "efg",
   totalCoins: 100,
   level: 4
}
]
```

Let's say I am finding rank of player with `_id = 4`.

How can i achieve this in mongoose.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Jaspreet? Can you please explain the question more.. I am assuming you want the rank of the player with _id 4 depending on what index the player will be in the DB if it was sorted on basis of the number of coins??

Comment: Yeah Avneeg, that's correct. In case, more than 1 player has same coins like players with _id 1, 4 and 5 has 100 coins, then sort them on the basis of their level (higher level, good rank). Basically, I want each player to see their rank when they login into app. Thanks

Comment: @AnveegSinha, would you be able to help me with above? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, which MongoDB version are you using? Asking because MongoDB v 5.0 provides a $rank method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are using MongoDB 5, then [$rank](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/rank/?_ga=2.107965441.2004710.1656169739-1413901579.1646908330) method should work (not 100% sure because I am using version 4.4 ).**

If you are not using 5.x then this should work

Step 1 - sorted the data based on level first and then totalCoins

Step 2 - pushed the sorted data in an array using group and push

Step 3 - unwinded the data and added the index of document based on sorted array with the help of includeArrayIndex and named it globalRank (name it whatever you want :) )

Step 4 - finally projected the data again and added 1 in globalRank so that the rank starts at 1 instead of 0 (this return the rank like 1.0 or 2.0... if you don't want this then you can avoid $add and handle this in frontend)

Step 5 - $match to find a specific index

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: "$name",
      totalCoins: "$totalCoins",
      level: "$level",
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      level: -1,
      totalCoins: -1,
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      arr: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id",
          name: "$name",
          totalCoins: "$totalCoins",
          level: "$level",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$arr",
      includeArrayIndex: "globalRank",
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$arr._id",
      name: "$arr.name",
      level: "$arr.level",
      totalCoins: "$arr.totalCoins",
      globalRank: { $add: ["$globalRank", 1] },
    },
  },
  { $match: { _id: 4 } },
]);
```

Comment: @Avneeg Sinha, thanks for your help. Yes, i am using v5.x. What does the _id: 1 means in `$project.

Comment: _id: 1 means that you want the _id in the result, if you write _id: 0 then _id will not be included in the result. Since we need the id for match we are writing 1

Comment: better explanation here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#:~:text=The%20projection%20parameter%20specifies%20which%20fields%20to%20return.%20The%20parameter%20contains%20either%20include%20or%20exclude%20specifications%2C%20not%20both%2C%20unless%20the%20exclude%20is%20for%20the%20_id%20field.

Comment: awesome work. I did a little change in your code. I need to sort it by totalCoins first, so I changed its position with level. Now, i am happy with result.

Comment: That's amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

```
collection.count({ 
    "$expr": {
        "$gt": [
            { "$add": [ "$totalCoins", {"$divide":["$level",10000] ] },
            100.0004
        ]
    }
})
```

The idea is to count the number of records with higher coins/level than the user. The idea I put here is to divide the level by maximum level + 1 (here the level is max 9999) so you will always end up with lower than 1 decimal. When you add the coins to that you will get 100.0004, coins.level . Then it is just to compare two numbers accordingly.

Comment: Note that since we count the number of players better than the current, you'll get 0 for the first/best. You'll need to add 1 to have the rank.

Comment: Hi Salketer, in your above code, where are we refering the _id? I mean, how can we check which player we are looking for?

Comment: In the example, I've used the value directly. 100.0004 were taken from the data you shown. I'm sure you could figure a way to just pass the ID, but I'm not too sure on how since it has been a while since I use MongoDB. One sure thing though is that you could grab the user's data using the id and then do this query.